# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(__APOLLO_CONTEXT__)') when using apollo provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo

i want to use query in my next app but when i'm using it i'm getting error Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(**APOLLO_CONTEXT**)')

so this is my apollo client:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default apolloClient;
```

layout.tsx:

```
import Footer from "./footer";
import Header from "./header";
import PageWrapper from "./pagewrapper";
import "@/styles/nav.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Next.js",
  description: "Generated by Next.js",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header></Header>
        <PageWrapper>{children}</PageWrapper>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page wrapper:

```
"use client";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { GlobalStyles, darkTheme, lightTheme } from "@/styles/ThemeConfig";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "./apollo";
import Header from "./header";

const PageWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    theme == "light" ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light");
    console.log(theme);
  };

  console.log(theme);
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme == "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Switch Theme</button>
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

export default PageWrapper;
```

where i use query:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import { GET_ADVERTS } from "@/graphql/advert";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

export default function Home() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ADVERTS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading....</p>;

  if (error) return <p>error: {error.message}</p>;

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>Recently added:</h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

query:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_ADVERTS = gql`
  query GetAdverts {
    getAdverts {
      id
      location
      price
    }
  }
`;
```

i tried to use  use client directive in page where i want to query data, but it's giving other error

Comment: You should check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that happens if you import `@apollo/client` first from a server component, but it should have been fixed in recent versions. Could you try upgrading Apollo Client to the most recent version (should be 3.8.4)?

Comment: Yes, now it works, but i have new problem, if i want to use query in slug page i'm getting error
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/errors/#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.8.4%22%2C%22message%22%3A43%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D

if i'm adding use client on top i'm getting
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.

Comment: You also need to use the helper package for Next.js as Golamrabbi Azad mentioned further up in his comment.

Comment: ./node_modules\next\dist\compiled\server-only\index.js
'server-only' cannot be imported from a Client Component module. It should only be used from a Server Component.

Comment: okay i fixed previous error but i still get this one
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/errors/#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.8.4%22%2C%22message%22%3A43%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D

Comment: You are probably using hooks in a component that is not a client component.
Are you aware that you are using React Server components and all that? Next.js adds a ton of concepts on top of classic React, you need to read their docs!